# Convert byte[] array to XDocument

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

I am trying to convert byte[] array into XDocument in WP. I have following code

```
 private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        svc.DownloadFileCompleted += new EventHandler<DownloadFileCompletedEventArgs>(svc_DownloadFileCompleted);
        svc.DownloadFileAsync("XMLFile1.xml");
    }

    void svc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, DownloadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bytes = e.Result;
        //string responseText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes,0,2048);  //  ASCII assumed
        //XDocument respnseXml = XDocument.Load(responseText);
        bytes = NullRemover(bytes);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(stream);
        }
    }
    private byte[] NullRemover(byte[] DataStream)
    {
        int i;
        byte[] temp = new byte[DataStream.Length];
        for (i = 0; i < DataStream.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (DataStream[i] == 0x00) break;
            temp[i] = DataStream[i];
        }
        byte[] NullLessDataStream = new byte[i];
        for (i = 0; i < NullLessDataStream.Length; i++)
        {
            NullLessDataStream[i] = temp[i];
        }
        return NullLessDataStream;
    }
```

I have created a web service which download the file. My code works fine. It converts byte[] into XDocument object. I am not sure this way is correct or not. Why there is need to use **MemoryStream**? Is it correct way to convert **byte[]** into **XDocument**?  Or there is any another way to convert?

Comment: Why do you need `NullRemover` at all? That suggests something else is broken - and it's not clear whether you're really happy just taking data up to the first 0 byte. But the use of `MemoryStream` is fine.

Comment: It gives am error "'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 51, position 12." that's why I am using this

Comment: But that just suggests that something is wrong when transferring the data - either that, or the XML is broken on the server. Either way, the solution is to make sure you get the right data to start with, not to just remove bad bytes as you go. You'll have no idea what *else* is wrong with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the posibility to Load XDocument directly by its Uri.

`XDocument.Load("localFile.xml")`

or

`XDocument.Load("http://example.com/remote.xml")`

If async downloading is mandatory for you - it's absolutely no problem, just use ThreadPool as Task to organize downloading in dedicated thread:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument document = null;

    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => document = XDocument.Load("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1323651/xml_test.txt"))
        .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(document.ToString()))
        .Wait();
}
```

Comment: It is mandatory for me. XML file is on web server, so it is mandatory

Comment: @Ajay, it's no problem at all. I have updated my answer with code sample, look at this again.

Comment: @Ajay, by the way your weired NullRemover can be replaced by this expression: array.TakeWhile(b => b != 0x00)